# Jboss deploying in root context

Tags: java, spring, maven, jboss

Yes, i know about `enable-welcome-root=false`, but cant find this in files. Use wildfly final or jboss eap 6.2. Where it is?
And why i need to add jboss-web.xml in WEB-INF?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The file in question is standalone.xml and is located in the following directory:

```
%JBOSS_HOME%/configuration/standalone.xml
```

You need to add `enable-welcome-root=false` in your virtual server definition in your standalone:

```xml
<virtual-server name="localhost" enable-welcome-root="false">
```

And create a jboss-web.xml file with the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<jboss-web>
    <context-root>/</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

Comment: In wildfly or last jboss versions no "%JBOSS_HOME%/configuration/" folder, domain, standalone, but no "configuration"

Comment: Checkout the standalone directory, and there should be a `standalone.xml`file in it.

Comment: Yes, standalone/configuration/standalone.xml, but in this file no "enable-welcome-root" parameter in any <subsysystem>

Comment: You need to add it, it shouldn't be there without you adding it. Find the virtual-server line, and add 'enable-welcome-root="false"'.

Comment: And i have no one <virtual-server>, or i have to add it manually too?

Comment: You shouldn't have to, look into your `domain.xml` instead and let me know if you find the mentioned line.

Comment: In domain/configuration/domain.xml no <virtual-server> too

Comment: You'll have to add it to your standalone then in your subsystem: `<virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
  <alias name="localhost"/>
  </virtual-server>`

Comment: In standalone.xml so many subsystems, create new, or add this code in specific place?

Comment: You can just add a subsystem: `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false"> 
          <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/> 
         <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true"> 
               <alias name="localhost"/> 
            </virtual-server> 
        </subsystem>`

Comment: Add this, server cant start, without this - all fine

Comment: Was there an already existing `default-virtual-server` subsystem?

Comment: No, i have no subsystem with "virtual-server" or any variations of "virtual" word

Answer (score 5):

And building on the answer provided by BelgianMyWaffle.

While J2EE defines the execution environment of a Java app it does not mandate how application servers are configured, so each has their own way to customize behaviour.

The following describes the jboss-web.xml:

- [JBoss Web Application Deployment Descriptor](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/7.0.x/appdev/jbossweb.html)

> The jboss-web.xml is an XML file containing the JBossWeb specific behaviour of a webapp. It replaces the Tomcat context.xml file. You need only to use it if you want properties and behaviour that extent the web.xml of the Servlet 3.0 specifications.

And the following lists all the various mechanisms supported by wildfly for customizing application deployment

- [Deployment Descriptors used In WildFly](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Deployment+Descriptors+used+In+WildFly)

> JBoss Web deployment descriptor. This can be use to override settings from web.xml, and to set WildFly specific options

Comment: Thanks for great answer, got it, but question about files actually not solved yet

Answer (score 5):

Solution:
Clean wildfly server, new clean project, just added jboss-web.xml to WEB-INF. Normal deploying and everything works fine.

Comment: Correct answer for Wildfly server

Comment: +1 for saved my life. Maybe, add the jboss-web.xml content to this answer:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>/</context-root>
</jboss-web>