# How to avoid application name in URL - RESTEasy Java 8

Tags: java, rest, maven, jboss, resteasy

I am very new to RESTEasy and the Java EE stack. I used to use the Spring framework and its modules instead. Today I thought to get familiar with Java EE's RESTEasy and dig through a list of problems so far, but finally my app started and I have also figured out that I need to type the url like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/com.maciej/message/asdasda
```

instead of:

```
http://localhost:8080/message/asdasda
```

as I did in spring rest

I wonder why is that? What should I configure to avoid typing **com.maciej** to the url?

Here are my config files, if you need more please let me know in comments and I will paste them.

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
        "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app>
    <display-name>RestEasy sample Web Application</display-name>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.maciej.MessageApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**Application class:**

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class MessageApplication extends Application {
    private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();

    public MessageApplication() {
        singletons.add(new MainRest());
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        return singletons;
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.maciej</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.maciej</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>com.maciej Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>JBoss repository</id>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>com.maciej</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

I use JBoss 9.0.0.Beta as my application server.
Thanks!

Comment: Add the `jboss-web.xml` seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21957225/2587435) to the `WEB-INF`. I get a bunch of warnings on the server log though, saying files normally found through the root path can be found.  But the app still works. Seems setting the context root to nothing overrides some system features.

Answer (score 0):

You can add @ApplicationPath("/") in your application class and this should work

Comment: The OP already has `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` in the web.xml. That's the same thing.

Comment: post owner and @peeskillet - By the way: @ ApplicationPath annotation is used when we want to create no-xml web app since jee6, isnt it? if this annotation is the same as mapping url pattern then how to register listener with no xml? however I had tried this solution already and it didnt help

Comment: @azalut I didn't start using Resteasy until 3.x.x. With this later version, there is a [resteasy-servlet-initializer](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-servlet-initializer), which implements the `ServletContainerInitializer` to load up the reasteasy servlet. I don't how it's done in 2.x.x versions. In the case of Wildfly, it actually uses 3.x.x. So you may want to change your dependency